# SQL Server 2012 Temp Filtered Index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012, key, filtered-index

I have a complex sproc that populates a #temp table on the order of 400,000 rows. There are duplicates identified with some row_number() hotness. Duplicates are deleted later in the sproc where the row number is > 1.

The slowest part is the delete, and adding an index helped. However, when run in production with many connections doing the same operation, a collision occurs when creating the same-named index on the temp table.

What is the proper way to get name-safe temporary indexes created on temp tables? I was thinking that creating a primary key on a combination of the row_number column and an ID might work but that might change more of the sproc code.

All ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure that there won't be any duplicate keys then that will indeed produce indexing. In a case where there need to be nullable index columns you would have to use a unique constraint instead. Also if you need multiple indexes then you can only use a primary key to provide one of then

To Demonstrate

The code below will create a temporary table with a Primary key and a unique constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(
id int, 
row_number int,
data varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id,row_number),
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (row_number,id)
)
```

The next bit of code will display the metadata from tempdb for the database object that underlies the local temporary table

```
SELECT 
QUOTENAME(s.name) SchemaName,
QUOTENAME(t.name) TableName,
QUOTENAME(i.name) IndexName,
i.type_desc IndexType,
i.is_unique is_unique
FROM tempdb.sys.schemas s
JOIN tempdb.sys.tables t ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN tempdb.sys.indexes  i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
where t.name like '#t[_]%'
```

You should see one table with a very long (128 Character) name like

```
[#t_______....______00000000002B]
```

(I've edited out some under scores to make it readable)

You should also see a Clustered Index whose name will be of the form

```
[PK__#t________6AE3842495F16AE5]
```

and a Unique non clustered Index whose name will be of the form

```
[UQ__#t________6C27FF361E0F4A70]
```

If you then create the local table in another session you'll see that an additional table and pair of indexes appear in tempdb with slightly different names